# Drupal 9 adding ---2 to field ID's

Tags: php, drupal

This line below somehow adds ---2 to certain fields.

I am in edit mode on form one.  Form one, is just one of many forms.

I want to get data from the full form form.  So I'm using this line below, which does work.

However, it adds --2 to certain fields. Just having this line below causes the issue.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
$form_all = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node, 'default');
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal tries to keep track of html element IDs output so as not to duplicate them.
it adds `--1`, `--2`, etc to de-duplicate html IDs via the [Html::getUniqueId function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AgetUniqueId/9.1.x).
You state "Form one, is just one of many forms", which points to this behaviour.
It is default drupal behaviour, your not doing anything wrong.